# CakePHP 2.0: Odd Auth Login Issue

Tags: cakephp

I have a strange issue going on as I try to learn and program website using CakePHP 2.0. I have worked in the past with version 1.3 but never seen this problem before. I am running the Simple Authentication and Authorization Application tutorial from the Cookbook (p.638) and I have checked and doubled checked to make sure it is the same.

The issue I am having is that when I call /users/login and fill out the form with bogus info or simply leave it empty. Auth logs it in and if I do `if($this->Auth->user())` I will receive true.

I have given up trying to understand why that is happening. It is strange....

/users/login

```
public function login(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Wrong login credentials!', 'default', array('class' => 'notification error closeable')); 
            }
        }
}
```

// Appcontroller.php ---- Auth configuration

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

 public function isAuthorized($user){
    if(isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin'){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your code where you load and configure AuthComponent?

Comment: I have added the Auth Component configuration code

Comment: I have this issue on CakePHP 2.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.Seems like i know what the problem is. Try doing:

```
if($this->Auth->login())
```

instead of passing it CakeRequest object.

The reason is:

In 2.0 `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 `$this->Auth->login($this->data)` would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful. Maybe thats why you are able to log in without any data.

Comment: +1. I was going to say this too. Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

Comment: Alright, that fixed the issue. However, I am not able to log in even the username/password combination I have setup on my database.

Comment: I have the ` public function beforeSave($options = array())` from the tutorial setup on my User.php model

Comment: Password Hashing seems to be fine when I first register a user. Is there something wrong with how it is being checked?

Answer (score 1):

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

Also try putting a `debug($user);` in beginning your isAuthorized method in AppController to see if its not getting a false from there.

Comment: hmm. Try adding `'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')` in the Auth array in AppController. I will update the code above too.

Comment: wow. Can you post your login view code also? I cant believe its not working lol...

Comment: I also add debug($user) as you suggested but nothing is displayed, although debug is set to 2 in the config.php file

Comment: I will add the login view file shortly

Comment: did you put an exit statement after debug so that the code halts right there?

Comment: WOW...It was the login view causing all this issue. I was not using the recomment $this->Form->input('username'), but I was using straight HTML code such as <input name="username".... THANKS SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP AND PATIENCE...

Comment: THANKS... Now I remember that if I wanted to use straight HTML code I had to use <input name="data[User][username]"....

Comment: Yes. thats how it expects the array data to be